# Android Dialog problem

Tags: android, dialog

I have a dialog appear when i press a button with dynamic data but when i press the same button  again the same data appears .I used log to find out why the next question is not shows there was a warning that  " Window already focused ignoring focus"   Below is the code

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{ AlertDialog.Builder dilog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 

switch (id)

    {

        case 99:
                String qa = showNext(); //gets question from database new  question  every time   

                dilog.setTitle("Team A player" + contactList.get(1).getName());
                dilog.setMessage(qa);

                dilog.setNegativeButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }   
                });

            break;

        }
        return dilog.create();


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create your Dialog and set its data inside onCreateDialog().
The system calls this if it does not have an object for the supplied dialog id.
Once created, this never gets called again. You have to modify the existing dialog with the newest data inside [Activity.onPrepareDialog()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareDialog%28int,%20android.app.Dialog,%20android.os.Bundle%29). That warning is not important, you can ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the method [onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareDialog%28int,%20android.app.Dialog%29) to updating data of your dialog every time the user press the button.